# Celery Workers as mirror frontends for Webservices

Tags: soap, celery, distributed-computing, worker

I am looking for a way to distribute jobs over SOAP-based Web-Services that can be randomly switched on and off on the Cloud, and can exist in one or several instances.

I went through the tutorials of Celery, and it seems a very interesting tool to distribute tasks.

However in my case, I don't have access to the hosts of the SOAP webservices , so I can't add any extra services on them. And I can't turn them into "worker nodes" for Celery.

I thought I could maybe create "mirrors" worker-nodes (one per SOAP web-services) on the machine that will be the like an intermediary between the Celery client and the SOAP-services.

My knowledge in Celery being limited, I wonder if this can be a good solution, and what would be the limits.

I have read in the documentation that it is possible to tune the number of processes executed on a machine with:

```
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY
```

The default value being *CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = number of CPUs*

It seems to me that I can use this option on the "Mirrors Workers" that would stand all on the same machine, each "mirror worker" have a *CELERYD_CONCURRENCY* value corresponding to how many execute I would allow on each SOAP service.

Does it seems acheivable with Celery, or is it very "hacky" ?

Comment: Hi Matt, your question I think is faar to generic, what this SOAP services actually do ? They will do most of the JOB ? Are they asynchronous or synchronous ? You need to post-process the data you receive in an heavy way ?